# Ubuntu 18.04 randomly reboots or shuts down every day

Tags: reboot

I installed as a dual-OS, with Win10 on a 1 TB HDD and Ubuntu 18.04 on a 512 GB SSD. It only reboots unexpectedly under Ubuntu, while it works fine under Windows 10. It has 32 GB memory, an i9-9900k CPU and Nvidia 2080 video adapter. I directly installed the 18.04 release rather than updating from other versions, and I use nvidia-430 graphic driver, so I don't think drivers should cause this problem. It will reboot even I only open a Chrome webpage or other low system usage.

I've almost read all the posts related to my problem online, but cannot find a solution. You know, the machine is powerful but drives me crazy.

I'll attach some information from the terminal. Please let me know if you need other info.

```
free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            31G        2.2G         26G        122M        2.3G         28G
Swap:          979M          0B        979M
```

---

```
ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 3 yw yw 4096 Aug 25 14:30 .
drwx------ 3 yw yw 4096 Nov 13 21:43 ..
drwxrwxr-x 5 yw yw 4096 Aug 25 14:30 dash-to-panel@jderose9.github.com
```

---

```
***reboot history***
last 
yw       :1           :1               Wed Nov 13 20:49   still logged in
reboot   system boot  5.0.0-36-generic Wed Nov 13 20:49   still running
yw       :1           :1               Wed Nov 13 19:24 - crash  (01:25)
reboot   system boot  5.0.0-35-generic Wed Nov 13 15:38   still running
yw       :1           :1               Wed Nov 13 09:55 - down   (09:24)
reboot   system boot  5.0.0-35-generic Wed Nov 13 09:55 - 19:20  (09:25)
yw       :1           :1               Wed Nov 13 09:44 - crash  (00:10)
reboot   system boot  5.0.0-32-generic Wed Nov 13 09:44 - 19:20  (09:35)
yw       :1           :1               Mon Nov 11 23:26 - crash (1+10:17)
reboot   system boot  5.0.0-32-generic Mon Nov 11 23:26 - 19:20 (1+19:53)
yw       :1           :1               Thu Nov  7 14:51 - 21:25 (1+06:33)
reboot   system boot  5.0.0-32-generic Thu Nov  7 11:52 - 21:27 (1+09:34)
yw       :1           :1               Thu Nov  7 06:41 - crash  (05:10)
reboot   system boot  5.0.0-32-generic Thu Nov  7 06:41 - 21:27 (1+14:46)
yw       :1           :1               Tue Nov  5 11:45 - 17:59 (1+06:13)
reboot   system boot  5.0.0-32-generic Tue Nov  5 11:45 - 17:59 (1+06:13)
yw       :1           :1               Tue Nov  5 11:44 - 11:45  (00:00)
reboot   system boot  5.0.0-32-generic Tue Nov  5 11:44 - 11:45  (00:00)
yw       :1           :1               Mon Nov  4 17:43 - 21:00  (03:17)
reboot   system boot  5.0.0-32-generic Mon Nov  4 17:42 - 21:00  (03:18)
yw       :1           :1               Mon Nov  4 17:32 - crash  (00:10)
reboot   system boot  5.0.0-32-generic Mon Nov  4 17:31 - 21:00  (03:29)
yw       :1           :1               Mon Nov  4 09:13 - 11:23  (02:10)
reboot   system boot  5.0.0-32-generic Mon Nov  4 09:12 - 11:23  (02:11)
yw       :1           :1               Sun Nov  3 18:32 - 20:36  (02:04)
reboot   system boot  5.0.0-32-generic Sun Nov  3 14:17 - 20:38  (06:20)
reboot   system boot  5.0.0-32-generic Sun Nov  3 18:44 - 18:45  (00:00)
yw       :1           :1               Sun Nov  3 13:55 - 18:29  (04:33)
reboot   system boot  5.0.0-32-generic Sun Nov  3 13:55 - 18:29  (04:34)
yw       :1           :1               Sun Nov  3 09:44 - crash  (04:10)
reboot   system boot  5.0.0-32-generic Sun Nov  3 09:43 - 18:29  (08:45)
reboot   system boot  5.0.0-32-generic Fri Nov  1 18:01 - 21:03  (03:02)
```

---

```
dmesg | grep -i error
[    0.992469] RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
[    2.916629] EXT4-fs (dm-0): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
```

---

```
This is the system logs before and after a reboot
10:08:12 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1574780892.880:45): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.gnome-logs.gnome-logs" name="/var/lib/snapd/desktop/icons/" pid=4296 comm="gnome-logs" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
10:08:11 kernel: kauditd_printk_skb: 33 callbacks suppressed
10:06:14 kernel: rfkill: input handler disabled
10:06:14 kernel: Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
10:06:08 kernel: snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC1D0: HDMI: invalid ELD data byte 11
10:05:58 kernel: capability: warning: `zerotier-one' uses 32-bit capabilities (legacy support in use)
10:05:57 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp4s0: link becomes ready
10:05:57 kernel: r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control off
10:05:56 kernel: snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC1D0: HDMI: invalid ELD data byte 33
10:05:54 kernel: rtw_pci 0000:03:00.0: start vif a4:fc:77:74:49:bf on port 0
10:05:53 kernel: input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input25
10:05:53 kernel: r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: Link is Down
10:05:53 kernel: aufs 4.x-rcN-20190204
10:05:53 kernel: Generic PHY r8169-400:00: attached PHY driver [Generic PHY] (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-400:00, irq=IGNORE)
10:05:53 kernel: intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain dram
10:05:53 kernel: Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
10:05:53 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1574780753.101:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper" pid=895 comm="apparmor_parser"
10:05:53 kernel: nvidia-uvm: Loaded the UVM driver in 8 mode, major device number 234
10:05:53 kernel: PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
10:05:53 kernel: [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20160202 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0
10:05:53 kernel: PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
10:05:53 kernel: nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  430.50  Thu Sep  5 22:39:50 CDT 2019
10:05:53 kernel: Adding 1003516k swap on /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1.  Priority:-2 extents:1 across:1003516k SSFS
10:05:53 kernel: PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
10:05:53 kernel: NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  430.50  Thu Sep  5 22:36:31 CDT 2019
10:05:53 kernel: rtw_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
10:05:52 kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone Surround as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input21
10:05:52 kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x19
10:05:52 kernel: r8822be: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
10:05:52 kernel: nvidia 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=io+mem
10:05:52 kernel: nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 236
10:05:52 kernel: rtw_pci 0000:03:00.0: pci msi enabled
10:05:52 kernel: ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
10:05:52 kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
10:05:52 kernel: nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
10:05:52 kernel: Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
10:05:52 kernel: nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
10:05:52 kernel: PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
10:05:52 kernel: rtw_pci 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
10:05:52 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz 14, total sz 20270

10:05:52 kernel: AES CTR mode by8 optimization enabled
10:05:52 kernel: AVX2 version of gcm_enc/dec engaged.
10:05:52 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rtl: examining hci_ver=07 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=07 lmp_subver=8822
```

Comment: What about syslog before a reboot/shutdown?

Comment: It's weird. I lost all the log before last crash. I'll check it again next time.

Comment: Hi there, I add the system logs. Please have a look